# Run c# console application from within MATLAB

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a c# console application that grabs some data. Is there a way in MATLAB to call the c# code to run and wait for the c# code to finish before it continues executing the rest of the MATLAB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following command:

```
dos(['"Path to executeable file" "' ]);
```

If you have to supply input argument as well then try this:

```
dos(['"Path to executeable file" "InputArgument" ']);
```